# Java version Error

Tags: updates, java, javascript

I try to install a software which is giving following error:
**No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 17.0.2 and at most 17.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.**

While, my java version is updated which is 18.0.2.

`java -version`

```
openjdk version "18.0.2-ea" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I try following command which I found from internet but it shows some older version, I am not understanding what's the issue is.

```
$ dpkg -l |grep default-jre

ii  default-jre                                2:1.11-72build2                         amd64        Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime
ii  default-jre-headless                       2:1.11-72build2                         amd64
```

Please help me to solve this error because I urgently want to use the software.

Comment: And what does `echo $INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME` reveal? How are you trying to install it - via apt, via dpkg, via snap, from source, with synaptic, … . Tell us the name and the command line, if available.

Comment: I used sudo apt install -y openjdk-18-jdk and sudo apt install -y openjdk-18-jdk for installation. Secondly, echo $INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME it's printing nothing just a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, beside that you postet 2 identical sudo-apt-commands in the comments, if I read it correctly, I now see and realize, that my English needs improvement. Maybe yours too?

`The version of the JVM must be at least 17.0.2 and at most 17.`

means yours >= 17.0.2 && yours < 18.

Since Java has a good tradition of being backwards compatible most of the time, Oracle introduced the non-LTS-versions, which might contain features, which the next version doesn't support. You should `apt remove` or `apt purge` the openjdk-18 version and install an openjdk-17 jdk.

I first refused to believe, that somebody would require jdk-17 but forbid -18, which is seldom, and therefore only experienced a mild irritation with `at most 17.`, corrected it in my silly head to `at least`.

So, you have a jdk-18 but need a jdk-17. If you need version 18 for other purposes, you may install the version 17 side by side to the 18-version, but if not, you may remove the version 18 by

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-18[Tab Tab]
```

and after 18, hit tab for autocompletion. This will be simpler to manage than switching between versions back and forth.

Then install the 17th version in a similar way:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-17[Tab Tab]
```

For Running Java apps, you essentially need the JRE (Java Runtime Environment), for developing with Java yourself, the JDK (Java Developer Kit). The JDK includes a JRE to run your (and foreign) programs.

The other packages (source, docs, ...-headless, ...) aren't necessary.

After doing that, you might try to install that software from scratch. Maybe it will find and set INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME itself. Else, you have to set it manually, but I'm not sure to which directory. Maybe your documentation of your program can answer that.
My guess would be /usr/lib/jvm/default-java or /usr/lib/jvm/java. At this point you might test it out by starting the application. If you find out what the right value is, you may set the variable in ~/.bashrc .

Comment: I apologize; I did not write it. When I try to install the software, the system prints me this notification "No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system. The version of the JVM must be at least 17.0.2 and at most 17. Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.".